# How can I fetch all possible flights between two cities?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called flight details as shown below:

[image]

Expected results:

- Bangalore to Chennai
- Bangalore to Delhi
- Bangalore to Kolkata
- Bangalore to Mumbai
- Chennai to Bangalore
- Chennai to Delhi
- Chennai to Kolkata
- Chennai to Mumbai
- Delhi to Chennai
- Delhi to Bangalore
- Delhi to Kolkata
- Delhi to Mumbai
- Kolkata to Chennai
- Kolkata to Delhi
- Kolkata to Bangalore
- Kolkata to Mumbai
- Mumbai to Chennai
- Mumbai to Delhi
- Mumbai to Kolkata
- Mumbai to Bangalore

not with same city.

Comment: Means you need all combination?

Comment: Yes, all other 4 cities.

Comment: have you able to fetch all records form database? if yes then show your code...

Comment: i'm writing MySQL query.. Not able to fetch desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT fl1.flight_city,fl2.flight_city FROM `flight_details` as fl1 JOIN `flight_details` as fl2 on fl2.fid != fl1.fid
```

Comment: Thank you! it works.. But we are considering same table, twice. It won't affect performance ?